# IIS Rewrite rule - check if a static file exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

Can someone tell me how to check if a static file exists as a rewrite rule condition.

I'm on IIS8, and my web app is it's own web site. I want to add a rewrite rule that checks if afile exists, and if so then applies the rewrite. Here's my code:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Find static gravatar" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^images/animage.png$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="i=(.+)" />
                <add input="/favicon.ico" matchType="IsFile" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/Somewhere/Else/images/{C:1}.png" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Hitting URL `/images/animage.png?i=SS`

In desperation I'm checking for a file I know exists - favicon.ico. If I comment out the 2nd condition that checks for the file, it works. With the condition in, it fails.

Comment: I'd guess it has to do with your path in the favicon input, see http://forums.iis.net/t/1190232.aspx?Rewrite+rules+simplify

Comment: @BrockHensley Yes :) Add that as an answer and I'll dish out the points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it works without the `<add input="/favicon.ico" matchType="IsFile" />` line, that line is suspect to me.

I'd have to guess it has to do with your `/favicon.ico` path, as the `matchType="IsFile"` is correct.

See [this link](http://forums.iis.net/t/1190232.aspx?Rewrite+rules+simplify) for more examples, their resolution was to not use a forward slash (/) but instead use a backslash (\).

> But I must to use not slash (/) in line <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/{R:1}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />. I must to use BACKSLASH (). That line is right: <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}{R:1}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

Comment: Thanks :) For me, it was the missing reference to {DOCUMENT_ROOT} that was causing it. So I needed `<add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/favicon.ico" matchType="IsFile" />`